# All emoticons have the same value in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String bear1 = "";
    String multiple = "\uD83D\uDC5A\uD83D\uDC5B\uD83D\uDC5C\uD83D\uDC55\uD83D\uDC5C\uD83D\uDC59\uD83D\uDC5E\uD83D\uDC61\uD83E\uDD84\uD83E\uDD93\uD83E\uDD84\uD83D\uDC34";
    String bear2 = "\ud83d\udc3b";
    String alien = "\uD83D\uDC7D";

    System.out.println("bear 1: " + bear1+ " multiple:" + multiple + " bear2: " + bear2 + " alien: " + alien);

    byte[] bear1B = bear1.getBytes();
    byte[] multipleB = multiple.getBytes();
    byte[] bear2B = bear2.getBytes();
    byte[] alienB = alien.getBytes();

    System.out.println("bear1B: " + Arrays.toString(bear1B));
    System.out.println("multiple: " + Arrays.toString(multipleB));
    System.out.println("bear2B : " + Arrays.toString(bear2B));
    System.out.println("alienB : " + Arrays.toString(alienB));

   
}
```

Output:

```
bear 1: ? multiple:????????????? bear2: ? alien: ?
bear1B: [63]
multiple: [63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63]
bear2B : [63]
alienB : [63]
```

It does not seem like a failure of console, becouse the bytes are all 63 although they are different emoticons in "multiple" variable. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it seems like java interprets all emoticons as a single value (63).

Comment: I have Intellij idea 2020.2.2, I haven't touched any settings. I don't know what you mean by "default charset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a charset issue. This will probably be fixed if you specify a charset like this:

```
byte[] bear1B = bear1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

with `StandardCharsets` being `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`.